# How to get current child (AutoID) from Firebase clicking TableViewCell - SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I need to get current child (AutoID) from Firebase by clicking TableViewCell. I have cells with names, and I need to get ID from current name (cell) and passing to another view controller where will be displayed more details for that person.
So, I'm new in swift and I want to know how to get the ID?
This is in my VC1 ->

'''

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedGuest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
  "GuestDetail") as! GuestDetailsViewController
        
        controller.guestUser = selectedGuest
       self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

//THIS IS MY VC 2

```
 func showGuestDetails(){
   ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("guests")
        ref.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                self.guestDetail.removeAll()

                for guests in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                    let guestObject = guests.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let name = guestObject?["guestName"]
                    let familyName = guestObject?["guestFamilyName"]
                    let phone = guestObject?["guestPhoneNumber"]
                    guard let email = guestObject?["guestEmail"] as? String,
                        email != self.guestUser?.guestEmail else {
                        continue
                    }

                    let guest = GuestModel(guestName: name as? String, guestFamilyName: familyName as! String, guestPhoneNumber: phone as? String, guestEmail: email as? String)
                    self.phoneNoLabel.text = guest.guestPhoneNumber
                    self.emailLabel.text = guest.guestEmail
                }
            }
        }
        self.nameLabel.text = guestUser!.guestName
    }
```

'''

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? How do you have the tableview set up? Where are you getting the names from to populated the tableview cells?

Comment: @ZacharyBell here is my code, I edited my question.

Comment: Only part of your code is formatted. It makes it confusing to read.

Comment: @ZacharyBell Now is edited.

Comment: this looks like a solution to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650296/swift-3-and-firebase-retrieve-auto-id-value-from-snapshot

Comment: @ZacharyBell Yes, this helped, but I need to get ID from the selected row, and with this link, I get all children when I select row.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `guests.key` inside the for-loop